# Grade Calculator JavaScript not running

Tags: javascript

I attempted to create a grade calculator for any value of grades in JavaScript. No parts of the code are executed when the code is run. Is there a blatant error in my code's syntax?
     Thanks,
         Ben

```
var numberofgrades = prompt("How many grades do you want to calculate?");
var countingvalue = 1;
var grades = [0];
var tempgrade = 0;
var averagetotal = 0;
for(i=0;i<numberofgrades;i++;){
if(countingvalue!=numberofgrades){
   var tempgrade= prompt("What is your "+countingvalue"th grade?")
   grades.push(tempgrade);
   countingvalue++;
}
else if(countingvalue==numberofgrades){
    for(var j=1;j=<numberofgrades;j++){
        averagetotal = grades[j]+averagetotal;
    }
}
    alert("Your average grade is: "+(averagetotal/numberofgrades));
```

Newest edited code-

```
var numberofgrades = prompt("How many grades do you want to calculate?");
var countingvalue = 1;
var grades = [0];
var tempgrade = 0;
var averagetotal = 0;
for(i=0;i<numberofgrades;i++){
if(countingvalue!=numberofgrades){
   var tempgrade= prompt("What is your "+countingvalue+"th grade?")
   grades.push(tempgrade);
   countingvalue++;
}
else if(countingvalue==numberofgrades){
    for(var j=1;j<=numberofgrades;j++){
        averagetotal = grades[j]+averagetotal;
    }
  }
}
alert("Your average grade is: "+(averagetotal/numberofgrades));
```

My syntax was just fixed for this issue, and it is now running. I am having problems adding two numbers instead of my program concatenating the values. Thanks for your help,
                Ben

```
var averagetotal = (grades[j]+averagetotal);
```

Here is the whole code.

```
var numberofgrades = prompt("How many grades do you want to calculate?");
var countingvalue = 0;
var grades = [];
var tempgrade = 0;
var averagetotal = 0;
for(var i=0;i<=numberofgrades;i++){
if(countingvalue!=numberofgrades){
    if(countingvalue==1){
    var tempgrade= prompt("What is your "+(countingvalue+1)+"st grade?");
    grades.push(tempgrade);
    countingvalue++;
}
    else if(countingvalue!=1){
    var tempgrade= prompt("What is your "+(countingvalue+1)+"th grade?");
    grades.push(tempgrade);
    countingvalue++;
    }
}
else if(countingvalue==numberofgrades)
{
    for(var j=0;j<numberofgrades;j++){
        var averagetotal = (grades[j]+averagetotal); // problem line
        alert(j+" "+averagetotal); //checking values
    }
}


}
alert(grades[0]); //just checking values
alert(grades[1]); //checking values
alert(averagetotal);
alert("Your average grade is: "+(averagetotal/numberofgrades));
```

Answer (score 1):

you have a syntax error. Instead of

```
for(i=0;i<numberofgrades;i++;)
```

it should be

```
for(i=0;i<numberofgrades;i++)
```

---

also instead of

```
var tempgrade= prompt("What is your "+countingvalue"th grade?")
```

it should be

```
var tempgrade= prompt("What is your "+countingvalue+"th grade?")
```

---

also instead of

```
for(var j=1;j=<numberofgrades;j++){
```

it should be

```
for(var j=1;j<=numberofgrades;j++){
```

---

and finally there seems to be a problem with your brackets - you are missing **}** at the end

Comment: Variables should be kept local, and a bit of whitespace helps: `for (var i=0; i<numberofgrades; i++)`.

Comment: Thanks, but the program still won't run.

Comment: Got it, I just usually like to guarantee that all of my variables have scope in the proper area.

Comment: It still will not run. Thanks again for spotting these simple syntax errors that I did not see.

Comment: There still must be another syntax error. I am looking.

Comment: hey - your code has many errors - I guess I numbered all - try now. Although it still got logical error... :)

Comment: I tried again. Even after fixing the brackets, it still is not running.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/n3zmjhpm/ - it works although doesn't give proper response I guess

Comment: I'll look for this logical error, for me this code is not running, ill post the most current code.

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
<script>
var numberofgrades = prompt("How many grades do you want to calculate?");
var countingvalue = 1;
var grades = [0];
var tempgrade = 0;
var averagetotal = 0;
for(var i=0;i<numberofgrades;i++){
if(countingvalue!=numberofgrades)
{
   var tempgrade= prompt("What is your "+countingvalue+"th grade?");
   grades.push(tempgrade);
   countingvalue++;
}
else if(countingvalue==numberofgrades)
{
    for(var j=1;j<numberofgrades;j++){
        averagetotal = grades[j]+averagetotal;
    }
}

    alert("Your average grade is: "+(averagetotal/numberofgrades));
}

</script>
```

Comment: Nope, I tried it with both firefox and chrome. Ill post the full page code.

Comment: try to open it new tab on chrome

Comment: Thanks, for all of your help. I will now fix the logic with the proper syntax.

Comment: any hints on the logic fix?

Comment: My variables are coencading not addencating at grades[j]+average total